# How can I get breadcrumbs from tree?

Tags: java, tree, breadcrumbs

I have tree like following example, where every leaf is object.

```
[1]
 |--[2]
 |   |--[3]
 |   |--[4]
 |       |--[5]
 |--[6]
```

Class structure is:

```
public class Node {
    private Integer id;
    private List<Node> children;
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<Node> getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<Node> children)
    {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

If leaf 3 is selected, then breadcrumbs are 1 2 3. How can I create breadcrumbs from this tree? I know how I can recursively create tree, but I don't know how I can select correct leafs to breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a parent pointer in the children. When you add children, the parent node can set the children's parent pointer to itself.

```
public class Node {
    private Integer id;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children;
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<Node> getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<Node> children)
    {
        this.children = children;
        for (Node child : children) {
            child.parent = this;
        }
    }
    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

You can then easily use this to build your breadcrumbs from a selected leaf node.

Comment: nice, but you should use a `child.setParent(this)` method instead of assigning the field directly (`child.parent = this`).

Comment: @Baz - Yes, that would be a refinement. Since this is all within the class itself (and private), the direct access is under control of the developer/maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

you could add the parent as a field to each node during creation. this way you can go up to the root from each object.